# Calculate how many days between 2 dates (one date may be blank) Google Spreadsheets

Tags: date, spreadsheet, date-arithmetic

In Google Spreadsheets, I am trying to list how many days a repair has been in our shop.  So, we have a column to enter when the item arrives.  We also have a column that I want to show "how many days" has the item been in for repair.

The arrival date can be empty because a Return Authorization number is given when a customer calls in for the repair, so the Row get created with the RA number and other details.

So I'd like to have that column to show how many days a repair has been in for repair considering the start date could be blank (if we have not yet received the item).

Any help would GREATLY be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the spreadsheet represents dates as a number of days, you can use the `now()` function to get the current date, guard against blanks with an `if` and just subtract:

I put this formula in cell `C2`, then copy/pasted to `C3` and `C4`

```
=if(A2="",0,if(B2="",int(now()-A2),int(B2-A2)+1))
```

Add a few arbitrary dates:

```
        A           B           C
1 | In         | Out       | Elapsed
2 |            |           | 0
3 | 5/31/2014  |           | 12
4 | 5/1/2014   | 5/15/2014 | 14
```

Comment: Thank you Joe!  Worked great!  I just could not get the "=" "," and "()" right!